# Remove split and store data to their different form tools using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove split data and store them in their regarding data tools using JavaScript.

Here is my code

```
function OnSuccessGetSchoolName(response) {
    alert(response.d);
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_firstletter.ClientID%>').value = MY;
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_secondletter.ClientID %>').value = Name;
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_thirdletter.ClientID %>').value = Is;
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_fourthletter.ClientID %>').value = Karan;
}
```

In alert it was showing the data i.e. "My, Name, Is, Karan". Now, I want to remove the split(',') and store them in different textbox different letter which I show above.

Comment: There is no `split(',')` to remove ?

Comment: I mean to say in alert it is showing data "my, name, is, karan" now i want to remove the ',' sign and store them

Comment: `response.d` is an array or a string?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb  it is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split()` the `response.d` and you will get an array, which you can assign to your textboxes.

```
function OnSuccessGetSchoolName(response) {
var values = response.d.split(',');
document.getElementById('<%= txt_firstletter.ClientID%>').value = values[0];
document.getElementById('<%= txt_secondletter.ClientID %>').value = values[1];
document.getElementById('<%= txt_thirdletter.ClientID %>').value = values[2];
document.getElementById('<%= txt_fourthletter.ClientID %>').value = values[3];
}
```

Find the working code below:

```js
function OnSuccessGetSchoolName(response) {
    var values = response.d.split(', ');
    document.getElementById('txt_firstletter').value = values[0];
    document.getElementById('txt_secondletter').value = values[1];
    document.getElementById('txt_thirdletter').value = values[2];
    document.getElementById('txt_fourthletter').value = values[3];
}

var response = { d :  "My, Name, Is, Karan"}

OnSuccessGetSchoolName(response);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_firstletter"><br>
<input type="text" id="txt_secondletter"><br>
<input type="text" id="txt_thirdletter"><br>
<input type="text" id="txt_fourthletter"><br>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I Assume like it is an array. but now from your comment I think its a string.

```
function OnSuccessGetSchoolName(response) {
    var res = response.d.split(',');
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_firstletter.ClientID%>').value = res [0];
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_secondletter.ClientID %>').value = res [1];
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_thirdletter.ClientID %>').value = res [2];
    document.getElementById('<%= txt_fourthletter.ClientID %>').value = res [3];
}
```

Comment: it is working but not accurate because only one word showing and also in tex_firstletter it is showing ',' (comma) also